# PostgeSQL: Window function behaves different in view

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, sql-view

Example table with one column **tmp_year_test.year** and values:

| year |
| --- |
| 2010 |
| 2011 |
| 2012 |

And now the logic

```
-- 2010 - OK
select
    max(year) over () as max_year
from tmp_year_test
where year = 2010

-- let's put it in the view
create view tmp_max_year_test as
select  
    year, 
    max(year) over () as max_year
from tmp_year_test

-- 2012 - WHY?
select  
    max_year
from tmp_max_year_test
where year = 2010
```

I thought I am fetching the same column as I do without the view, but the value is different. Why?
I need to store the wind. function logic in the view and get it filtered. Is there a way to achieve it?

**EDIT:**
A better example of the desired behavior:

Example 1

```
select  
    *
from tmp_max_year_test
where year in (2011,2012)
```

| year | max_year |
| --- | --- |
| 2011 | 2012 |
| 2012 | 2012 |

Example 2

```
select  
    *
from tmp_max_year_test
where year in (2010,2011)
```

| year | max_year |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 2011 |
| 2011 | 2011 |

Comment: In the first query, you are filtering by `year = 2010` *before* applying the window function to only the selected rows. When querying the view, you are filtering for `year = 2010` *after* applying the window function to all rows.

Comment: The query on the view is equivalent to `SELECT max_year FROM (SELECT year, max(year) OVER () AS max_year FROM tmp_year_test) AS tmp_max_year_test WHERE year = 2010`

Comment: Btw, why are you doing `max(year)` at all when you already select rows from a specific year only?

Comment: `WHERE` is applied before window functions are calculated. The view is like a subquery: it calculates the window function before the `WHERE`.

Comment: It's confusing bcs it works with classical agg
`SELECT max_year FROM (SELECT year, max(year) AS max_year FROM tmp_year_test group by 1) AS tmp_max_year_test WHERE year = 2010` 
I need that behaviour for the WF.

Comment: Please look at the last 2 queries in my [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/wSQp5FDr)

Comment: @shtyler Then why did you define your view using `max(year) OVER ()`  when you actually want `max(year) … GROUP BY year`?

Comment: @shtyler As the answer explains, you need to add `PARTITION BY year` to your window function to achieve the grouping ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qgH__ZuG))

Comment: `PARTITION BY year` freezes the max_year for a year and does not return the max anymore when more years are filtered.

Comment: @shtyler If that's what you want, you cannot use a `VIEW`. A view is a relation with a certain set of rows, if you filter it, you'll only get a subset of those rows. The values in the rows cannot change depending on which rows you are selecting. You could use an sql function, or you should simply do this without a view.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the view, there is no `partition by` clause in the window function, so the aggregate function is applied on the entire table. Since 2012 is the greatest values of all in the source table, the view contains the various years (`year`) and the constant value `2012` as `max_year`.

The [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) has a very similar example and adds

> `SELECT salary, sum(salary) OVER () FROM empsalary;`
> Above, since there is no ORDER BY in the OVER clause, the window frame
> is the same as the partition, which for lack of PARTITION BY is the
> whole table; in other words each sum is taken over the whole table and
> so we get the same result for each output row.

In the 1st query, you are restricting the `max` computation to a single row, the one for the year 2010 so the max_year is also 2010.

To achieve a similar result when using the view, you need to specify a `partition` in the `over` clause:

```sql
create or replace view tmp_max_year_test as
select  
    year, 
    max(year) over (PARTITION BY year) as max_year
from tmp_year_test;
```

Comment: Right. So is there a way to evaluate the WF after filtering a view? It seems to work when I use a classical agg
`SELECT max_year FROM (SELECT year, max(year) AS max_year FROM tmp_year_test group by 1) AS tmp_max_year_test WHERE year = 2010` 
which is not an option for me, because my source table is complex and contains facts.

Comment: I specified the output behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your view has these 3 records:

```
select  
    year, 
    max(year) over () as max_year
from tmp_year_test
```

records:

| year | max_year |
| --- | --- |
| 2010 | 2012 |
| 2011 | 2012 |
| 2012 | 2012 |

So, when asking :

```
select  
    max_year
from tmp_max_year_test
where year = 2010
```

It seems pretty logical that `2012` is returned...

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/XpH0JTGq) for the complete SQL stuff.